# How to stop ffmpeg process after it has finished processing in C#?

Tags: c#, timer, ffmpeg

I am trying to stop the ffmpeg process once it has finished doing what I want it do, but I am not able to find a way.

Here is what I have done.

```
//Process for running ffmpeg
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.FileName = ffmpegfile;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = commandtorun;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;


process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();

process.Close();
```

The problem is ffmpeg does not tell the process to stop after it has finished executing, so I cant use WaitForExit() call.

What i tried doing is

```
commandtorun = commandtorun+ " && exit";
```

to force ffmpeg to close after it finishes executing. Now this works when I try in cmd.

But when I do the same thing in C#, ffmpeg closes down as soon as the command is executed.

Is there any way to force ffmpeg or the process to close after the processing is done ?

Comment: How does it work in cmd?

Comment: @Dolev in cmd, when I add in the " &&  exit", it processes the file and exits the command

Comment: Did you try using a shell execute?

Comment: @Dolev it works when I use a shell execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;`

This will force the process to run in shell. I don't know why it did not work using standard execution but sometimes processes behave differently in shell execute.